# Python API Call gets rejected with "connection reset by peer"

Tags: python, api, iot

The code below is trying to send an API POST request to a Shelly Plug S, setting it up to run on my network without having to open every single device's config site or pair with their native app.

```py
import http.client

ssid = input("WiFi SSID: ")
pwd = input("Password: ")

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("192.168.33.1", "80")

payload = 'ssid='+ssid+'&key='+pwd+'&ipv4_method=dhcp&enabled=true'
headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}
conn.request("POST", "/settings/sta", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data. Decode("utf-8"))
```

Problem is, [Errno 104] is thrown "Connection reset by peer"
traceback:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/smarthome/shelly.py", line 12, in <module>
    conn.request("POST", "/settings/sta", payload, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1282, in request
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1328, in _send_request
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1277, in endheaders
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1037, in _send_output
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 975, in send
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1454, in connect
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 512, in wrap_socket
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1070, in _create
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1341, in do_handshake
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Sending the request from Postman, the command goes out and it does as I ask, it connects to my WiFi. (In fact, the python code is generated by Postman from the working request).

Update: Running the python script (with basically no changes) now throws a new error,
`ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`

Answer (score 1):

Won't mark this as an answer as it's really more of a workaround but I dithched python and just used `wget` in a shell script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

WIFINAME=$1
PWD=$2

 wget --quiet \
  --method POST \
  --header 'Accept: */*' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --body-data "ssid=$WIFINAME&key=$PWD&ipv4_method=dhcp&enabled=true" \
  --output-document \
  - http://192.168.33.1/settings/sta
```